# Como Verificar numeros contido numa consulta em um campo

Tags: php

Como Verificar se um id está contido numa range de ids dentro de um campo no banco de dados

Nessa tabela a baixo eu lista a "id_rota" ele me retorna Ids separados por virgula 16,17,18,19.....

```
$numero = $_GET["numero"];
$bd = new MySQLiConnection();   
$sql3 = $bd->prepare( "SELECT * FROM pax where id_rfid = ?  "  ) or exit( 
$mysqli->error );
$sql3->bind_param('s', $id_rfid); // Coloca o valor de $data no lugar da 
primeira interrogação (?) 
$sql3->execute();
$resultcar = $sql3->get_result(); 
while( $row = $resultcar->fetch_assoc() )
{                               
$id_rota1 = $row['id_rota'];//   16,17,18,19,20

}
```

preciso verificar se um numero está la dentro de "$id_rota"  , se estiver contido fazer algo

exemplo se numero 17 estiver dentro $id_rota echo "ok";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta utilizar a função `explode` para gerar um *array* a partir da sua *string* e verificar com `in_array`:

```
if (in_array($numero, explode(',', $row['id_rota']))) {
    // Número está na sequência de ids
}
```